# Como mapear um parâmetro da requisição http para uma enum no java?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, java-ee, jersey

Estou fazendo uma requisição ajax assim:

```
$.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url : apiURL + '/play',
    dataType : "json",
    data : {
        against : "ANYBODY"
    },
    success : function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        // ...
    },
    error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        // ...
    },
});
```

E recebendo (com sucesso) os dados no servidor assim:

```
@POST
@Path("play")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Game play(@FormParam("against") String param) {
    Against against = Against.valueOf(param);
    switch(against) {
    case ANYBODY:
    // ...
```

Percebam que `Against` é uma enum trivial:

```
public enum Against {
    ANYBODY, ANY_FRIEND, A_FRIEND;
}
```

**Minha dúvida:** é possível receber a enum diretamente, como no exemplo abaixo? Vocês conhecem alguma alteração no código javascript e/ou java que me permita isso?

```
@POST
@Path("play")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Game play(Against against) {
    switch(against) {
    case ANYBODY:
    // ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segundo a [documentação do Jersey](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/jaxrs-resources.html#d0e1889), os tipos usados nos parâmetros anotados com `@*Param` (como `@QueryParam` e `@FormParam`) deve sem enquadrar em um dos seguintes itens:

1. Ser um tipo primitivo
2. Ter um construtor que aceite um único argumento String
3. Ter um método estático chamado `valueOf` ou `fromString` que aceite um único parâmetro String
4. Ter uma implementação registrada da extensão SPI do JAX-RS `javax.ws.rs.ext.ParamConverterProvider` que retorne uma instância de `javax.ws.rs.ext.ParamConverter` capaz de fazer uma conversão de uma String para o tipo desejado
5. Ser uma collection como `List<T>`, `Set<T>` ou `SortedSet<T>`, onde `T` satisfaça os itens 2 ou 3 acima.

Como um `Enum` possui o método [`valueOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html), o mesmo se enquadra no item 2. Logo seria perfeitamente possível fazer:

```java
public Game play(@FormParam("against") Against param) { 
    ...
}
```

---

**Atualização**

Há uma outra solução que costumo usar com tipos personalizados, que é escrever um [`MessageBodyReader`](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/message-body-workers.html#d0e5581) para tratar a desserialização automática desse tipo.

Talvez seja possível escrever um genérico para enums, mas nunca tentei.

Comment: Não fica exatamente como eu queria, pois ainda tenho que manter o `MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED` e o `@FormParam`, mas já melhora consideravelmente. Obrigado.

Comment: @André Adicionei mais uma opção. Veja se pode te ajudar. Infelizmente estou meio sem tempo para fazer um exemplo funcional, mas se você conseguir entender como funciona o `MessageBodyReader`, provavelmente vai resolver seu problema.